# How to display full path and git branch on Mac terminal

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I find someone's mac terminal can display both the full path and git branch like this :
[git branch and full path on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCiLf.png)

I look at some materials and just can display the full path or git branch on the terminal seperatly. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT:

Open `bash_profile` in the terminal:

```sh
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and then add following in the `bash_profile`-file:

```sh
# to see always fullpath and current git-branch
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]: \[\033[34m\][\w]\[\033[m\]\[\033[32m\]\$([[ -n \$(git branch 2> /dev/null) ]] && echo)\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[m\] \$ "

# find out current branch
parse_git_branch() {
        git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ \1/'
}
```

After that, restart the *Terminal* and then it works like follow:

```
username: [~/path/to/current/directory] current-branch $
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it just shows full path and not include the git branch

Comment: I've edited the answer, now I hope it meets your requirements!

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: yep! it's helpful! Thanks again! I have been used oh-my-zsh for my shell, it's easier to set up.

Answer (score 0):

add below line in .zshrc file will solve your problem

```
parse_git_branch() {
git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/[\1]/p'
}
COLOR_DEF='%f'
COLOR_USR='%F{243}'
COLOR_DIR='%F{197}'
COLOR_GIT='%F{39}'
NEWLINE=$'\n'
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PROMPT='${COLOR_USR}%n@%M ${COLOR_DIR}%d ${COLOR_GIT}$(parse_git_branch)${COLOR_DEF}$ '
source ~/.bash_profile
```