# Setting branch visible on Mac Big Sur

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I am new here.
Now im trying to set branch name visible in terminal, I have found some guides about it, but nothing works. So what I do:

1. I installed Git to the Mac
2. Open terminal and create .bash_profile

   ```
   touch ~/.bash_profile
   ```
3. Open file in code editor
4. Add there this code:

   ```
   # Git branch in prompt.
   parse_git_branch() {
       git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
   }
   export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
   ```
5. Update the file with this command:

   ```
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```

But nothing happens, in the end I got this thing:

```
\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $
```

Appreciate for any help!

Comment: This is interesting. Are you sure you're using Bash and not something like Zsh？

Comment: @iBug Sorry, im rly new) So may be i dont understand differences between Terminal in LaunchPad and Bash. Is it different terminals? I know that if im working on Windows, i can press "Git bash here" so it will be Bash Terminal and i also may open "cmd" so i ll be Windows Terminal. How to open Git Bash on mac? I bought mac 1 day ago))

Comment: Have you restart the *Terminal*? Otherwise look at my answer in this [stackoverflow-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64878744/how-to-display-full-path-and-git-branch-on-mac-terminal/64884110#64884110). I hope this helps

Comment: @SwissCodeMen omg, it rly works. I tried to add to bash.profile a lot of different codes, but nothing works. But your code is absolutely works. Do you know what was wrong with code which is in my post? Many thanks!

Comment: @k2wln your code in the question works fine for me. I think the problem was, that you  didn't  restart the terminal after the changes in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen i did a lot of times)

Comment: My example works and yours doesn‘t? That would be very special, then the code is very similar...

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of macOS the default shell is zsh, not Bash, so you will want to either:

1. Use a zsh-specific prompt setup. See [these docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) for the embeddable prompt codes. Note that you will need to use a `.zshrc` file instead of a `.bashrc` file.
2. Change your Terminal config to use Bash.